# Git is slow on pushing submodules change to origin

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm using git where I have a repo containing about 40 (!) submodule repos.

Whenever I do a git `git push origin master` it's very slow on the `remote: Processing changes` action.

Is there any way I can speed up the push? Gerrit is used as a backend but I'm overriding the HEAD:refs/for/master to short circuit the review mechanism.

PS. I know I have alot of sub repos and that might not be optimal, but that's how it is and the question isn't about this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK found the problem:

The top repo was tracking master branch. This means when I push to origin in each sub repo the top repo is updated automatically (in Gerrit).

I didn't understand this so I also did a push on the top repo and this caused the very long processing time.

Dunno why though.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can speed up the push?

With the next git 2.12.0 (Q1 2017), that process (of testing if submodules need to be pushed) will be **much faster**.

See [commit 250ab24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/250ab24ab3a35d5857855a2e00483dcd8867fdca), [commit 5b6607d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b6607d23f8a262e1c0ede954f0477664934eed8), [commit 9cfa1c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9cfa1c260fd10dadb2dfbb62f8e120a10cabfd06), [commit 1473944](https://github.com/git/git/commit/147394470c4be34038e520e74a017da6a3745e90) (16 Nov 2016) by [Heiko Voigt (`hvoigt`)](https://github.com/hvoigt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit af952da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/af952dac7a6997e587ded97e4051a927e5384423), 16 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### serialize collection of changed submodules
>
> To check whether a submodule needs to be pushed we need to collect all
>   changed submodules. Lets collect them first and then execute the
>   possibly expensive test whether certain revisions are already pushed
>   only once per submodule.
>
> There is further potential for optimization since we can assemble one
>   command and only issued that instead of one call for each remote ref in
>   the submodule.